# Struggling with Swift Protocol and `some` Keyword

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have a `Processor` protocol:

```swift
protocol OutputProvider<OutputType>: AnyObject {
    associatedtype OutputType
    var cachedOutput: OutputType? { get set }
}

protocol Processor: OutputProvider {
    associatedtype InputType
    associatedtype InputProvider: OutputProvider<InputType>

    func process(input: InputType) -> OutputType
    
    var inputProvider: InputProvider { get }
}

extension Processor {
    func process() {
        if let nextProcessor = inputProvider as? any Processor {
            nextProcessor.process()
        }
        guard let input = inputProvider.cachedOutput else {
            cachedOutput = nil
            return
        }
        self.cachedOutput = self.process(input: input)
    }
}
```

Each object which conforms to the `Processor` protocol has a (type safe) reference to an `inputProvider` (which conforms to the `OutputProvider` protocol with matching `OutputType` for the processors `InputType`).

So the idea is, that by calling the `process()` function in the last of a chain of `Processor` objects, each `Processor` can *process* the output of its `inputProvider`, down the chain until the initial *input* is reached (the real setup would be more complex and more dynamic):

```swift
final class Input: OutputProvider {
    var cachedOutput: String?
}

final class P1: Processor {
    ...
}

final class P2: Processor {
    ...
}

let input = Input()
input.cachedOutput = ...

let chain = P2(inputProvider: P1(inputProvider: initialInput))
chain.process()
print(chain.cachedOutput)
```

But now I've go stuck at the implementation of a concrete Processor:

```
final class P1: Processor {
    init(inputProvider: some OutputProvider) {
        self.inputProvider = inputProvider // ERROR 1
    }
    
    func process(input: String) -> Int {
        input.count
    }
    
    var cachedOutput: Int?
    
    let inputProvider: some OutputProvider<String> // ERROR 2
}
```

- Error 1: *Cannot assign value of type 'some OutputProvider' to type 'some OutputProvider & AnyObject'*
- Error 2: *Property declares an opaque return type, but has no initializer expression from which to infer an underlying type*

I already tried many things, but nothing seems to satisfy the swift compiler.

I thought, that the `some` keyword is exactly for a use case like this. But now I'm not so sure anymore :)

Am I on a completely wrong path here or did I just get some obscure detail wrong?

Comment: This is almost precisely the example from here: https://youtu.be/QCxkaTj7QJs?t=533 (matt's explanation is all correct, but inter-dependent protocols are the wrong approach to this problem) The talk pre-dates modern `any` and `some` syntax and `where` causes on associated types (which are now legal), but the basic issues haven't changed. `some` is not the tool you want for this, anyway (as matt notes)

Answer (score 1):

You have to resolve the generics; every type must be known absolutely at compile time. Thus, in your class P1, you must define `inputProvider` as a *specific* type that adopts OutputProvider.

Looking at the same matter from a different direction, the Processor requirement

```
var inputProvider: InputProvider { get }
```

can be satisfied only by a declaration that starts

```
var inputProvider: InputProvider
```

You cannot arbitrarily insert `some`; that's not what the requirement says.

Here's a working example of the kind of chain you're trying to create (omitting the entire `process` method, which is a red herring for purposes of the issue):

```
protocol OutputProvider: AnyObject {
    associatedtype OutputType
    var cachedOutput: OutputType? { get set }
}

protocol Processor: OutputProvider {
    associatedtype InputType
    associatedtype InputProvider where InputProvider: OutputProvider, InputProvider.OutputType == InputType

    var inputProvider: InputProvider { get }
}

class P1: OutputProvider {
    var cachedOutput: String?
}

class P2: Processor {
    typealias InputType = String

    var inputProvider: P1

    var cachedOutput: Int?

    init(inputProvider: P1) {
        self.inputProvider = inputProvider
    }
}
```

I should just add that if you want to see this kind of chaining in action, you have no further to look than the Combine framework; this sort of thing is exactly how it works.